# User Control property with Open dialog box in VB or C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, user-controls

I need to know how to create a property  in my user control like font property in textbox control.

That property should open a dialog box to place different values.

[image]

Comment: That's just a button with the text "..." - which when clicked, opens a dialog with whatever you want in it. Then when you close the dialog, if you didn't hit cancel, set whatever properties you want. Not sure what the question is exactly?

Comment: Property has default value, but I need to change this value from dialog box.

Comment: @neminem I think the OP is saying that they want to change the behavior or the Properties window in the designer for their control, not add something to the control itself.

Comment: the type of editor used in the props panel is totally dependent on the data type.  it is not a stylistic thing where you pick what you want.  What property is this for and what is its the `Type`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but it requires lots of bits.

The walk through is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx), but since link only answers are not always useful, here are the highlights.

1. Create a view control for the editor
2. Derive a custom editor class from the UITypeEditor
3. Override the GetEditStyle method to use your custom editor class
4. Override the EditValue method to wire up the custom editor to the property value